# How to declare generic Types?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know how to declare this correctly and would be happy about an answer
[image: How do I declare this correctly?]

Comment: What? The image is blank.

Comment: now its here : )

Answer (score -1):

The picture did not load corretct I hope it works  now
[image: thats my problem]

Comment: This isn't an answer.  You instead can re-edit your question to provide more information. 2. Generally avoid asking questions as images.